# Difference between <%: %> and <%#: %> in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-4.5

I know that we can `<%: %>` syntax for html encoding that is introduced in .Net 4. But I was reading new features of Asp.Net 4.5, and I got that we have another type i-e `<%#: %>` that is used for encoding the result of databind expression.
I am confuse with this.

```
What is the difference between <%: %> and <%#: %> in Asp.Net
```

Please explain both of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way that `<%: %>` is the HTML encoded version of `<%= %>`, the `<%#: %>` tag is the HTML encoded version of `<%# %>`.

The `<%#: %>` tag does the same as `<%# %>`, but then it calls `Server.HTMLEncode` on the string.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET provides what's called a "binding" syntax to link HTML markup and controls to values extracted from data sources or other variables; that binding syntax is seen as something like:

```
<%# someVariable %>
```

The following colon merely extends the new "auto-HtmlEncode" behavior to the results of those bnding expressions.

Hope that helps.